# If A1 is blank move text in B1 to next row

Tags: excel, sorting, columnsorting, vba

I have a table where A1 has country name, B1 has price, and some fields in country is deleted, is there a forumla to force B1 to move all values to next available field, below image example.

- Grenada is 131.5 (Correct)
- Guadeloupe is 81.0 (correct)
- Guatemala should be 131.5
- Guinea should be 98.0
- Guyana should be 102.0
- Guyane French should be 185.5 and so on

[image: This is the table picture]

Comment: formula to do it in B1 no.  a formula to place a corrected list in say column C probably.  If you are open to VBA as per your tag, then VBA can alter column B based on blank cells in column A.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A1="","",INDEX($B:$B,ROW(A1)-COUNTA($A$1:A1))
```

Place the above in C1 and copy down as far as needed and it should generate a corrected list in the neighbouring column.  This list could then be copied and values pasted back into B followed by a deletion of column C.

There is a much cleaner way to do this in VBA but my brain is shot at the moment and I am not a VBA programmer to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the `Column A`
2. Press <kbd>F5</kbd>
3. Select `Special`
4. Select `Blanks`
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
6. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
7. Press Ok

Done!